# Getting Access denied in asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I published `API` who execute DLL into `IIS` asp.net core application where I'm getting access denied to my files. I read a lot of forums about this error:

To execute DLL in webconfig I have:

```
<add key="myFile" value="D:\WebSites\business.myapi.WebApi\Web\App_Data\bin\myfile.NCD" />
```

In WebConfig I try adding:

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
  <customErrors mode="True" />
  <trust level="Full" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
```

Also I set `IIS_IUSRS` user with full permisions and .NET Trust Levels are setted to Full (internal)

Nothing works, I'm really desesperated.

Error:

> Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Access is denied. at ...
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer Inner Exception:
>   Access is denied.

Someone have an idea why this issue still appearing after add permissions?

Comment: As Webservers are always on, they are often put under very restrictive user rights. Read access to the programm and content directory are usually the top. Maybe you get access to a temp folder below content. So could it be the server/it's useraccount (a Windows Service) simply lacks the right to read there.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core, 99% of time you **don't** touch the web.config file. You are doing something wrong

Comment: I forget to specify: My API is only used to execute a DLL file so I added a key read file like:    `<add key="MyFile" value="D:\WebSites\business.myapi.WebApi\Web\App_Data\bin\myfile.NCD" />` @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: Can you check the directory permissions all the way till root directory?

Comment: Yap, full permissions there @PratikGaikwad